# How to access string resources correctly from strings.xml in Xamarin android resources?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-resources

I can't get the string from my resource file and I can't find a working solution. I've worked with the official [Xamarin Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization) and the [example App](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-samples/tree/master/TaskyL10n).
It's a xamarin forms project and I want the app to show in german/english. The ios part works already.

What I have so far:

My Language-Files in the following folder structure:

Resources > values > Strings.xml

Resources > values-de > Strings.xml

Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="barcodescanner_toptext">QR-Code Scanner</string>
  <string name="barcodescanner_bottomtext">Please scan QR-Code.</string>
  <string name="barcodescanner_cancelbuttontext">Cancel</string>
  <string name="barcodescanner_flashbuttontext">Flash</string>
  <string name="barcodescanner_errortext">Scan canceled</string>
</resources>
```

The property "Build Action" of the Strings.xml files are set to "AndroidResource". In the Resource.Designer.cs the strings are visible.

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f070041
public const int barcodescanner_bottomtext = 2131165249;
        
// aapt resource value: 0x7f070042
public const int barcodescanner_cancelbuttontext = 2131165250;
        
// aapt resource value: 0x7f070044
public const int barcodescanner_errortext = 2131165252;
        
// aapt resource value: 0x7f070043
public const int barcodescanner_flashbuttontext = 2131165251;
        
// aapt resource value: 0x7f070040
public const int barcodescanner_toptext = 2131165248;
```

Inside of my Scanner.cs file I make the call like in the tutorial:

```
BarcodeScanner.TopText = Resources.System.GetText(Resource.String.barcodescanner_toptext);
```

I have to use ".System." because there is no "GetText" directly on Resources. If I press "." after Resource.String I get all my resourcestrings to select. But if I run the app on android I get the following error:

> No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f070040
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'xyz.ViewModels.MainViewModel' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070040

What I've done so far:

- cleaned and rebuild the solution
- deleted the obj and bin folders
- restarted all including my computer
- deinstalled the app from the smartphone

I don't know what I should do next?
Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**
If it's something useful, Visual Studio shows me on this part "Resource.String.*barcodescanner_toptext*" the following message: "Ambiguous reference: int barcodescanner_toptext (in class String) int barcodescanner_toptext (in class String) match"

Comment: Have you tried by reflection? Like this: `var resourceValue = (string)typeof(Resource.String).GetField("barcodescanner_toptext").GetValue(null);`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I tried your code sample without the string cast, because I get a cast exception. As a result I get resourceValue: 2131165248